# Oracle Hibernate single insert slow performance intermittently

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have a few Oracle tables in my application and intermittently (for 5 percent of requests) the insertion in tables is taking time. We chose a few tables and have logged everything to figure out root cause and as per that I can see the time taken to insert in those takes sometime 2s-10s.

I want them to be in milliseconds always.

I am sharing one table here which does not have any index apart from primary key.

```
@Data
@Entity
@DynamicUpdate
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "AUDIT_ENTITY")
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
public class AuditEntity extends BaseEntity {

    @GenericGenerator(name = "AuditSeqGen", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator", parameters = {
            @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = "sequence_name", value = "AUDIT_SEQ"), @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = "initial_value", value = "300"),
            @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = "increment_size", value = "1") })

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "AuditSeqGen")
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "MSISDN")
    private String msisdn;

    @Column(name = "TYPE")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Type type;

    @Column(name = "VAL")
    private String val;

    @Column(name = "APP_ID")
    private String appId;
    
    @Column(name = "CLIENT")
    private String client;
    
    @Column(name = "PROD")
    private String prod;

    @Column(name = "CIRCLE")
    private String circle;
    
    @Column(name = "ELIGIBLE", columnDefinition="NUMBER(1,0) DEFAULT 1")
    @Builder.Default
    private boolean eligible = true;
    
    @Column(name = "C_ID")
    private String cId;
    
    @Column(name = "REQUEST_ID")
    private String requestId;

}
```

This is how I have logged to find out the time:

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
sRepo.save(sEntity);
log.info("save db time", System.currentTimeMillis()-start);
```

I have generated Hibernate stats as well to calculate the time. But from those logs I cannot see any session having time more than 1 second.

Also from DB trace logs as well, for a particular time when I was doing analysis, I could see long response times in my application. However DB trace logs showed query was executed in milliseconds.

Comment: Well it's probably something in your application then, yes?  Have you tried profiling the app or inserting log statements so that you can determine where the app is slow?  Which methods are the slowest?

Comment: @markspace We have logged everything. So there is nothing in the business logic. Just to make sure, we have put log.info just after repo.save() and computed the time taken to call this JPA function only.Also this is happening intermittently only for few percent of requests

Comment: So you're saying `repo.save()` is intermittently slow?  What about garbage collection are you tracking that?

Comment: @markspace, Yes this part is intermittently slow as per my application log. But if at the same time I check oracle trace i cannot find  any latency there. 
Also I have not tracked garbage collection, but will that help?

Comment: Tracking garbage collection could help, if the garbage collection is responsible for the intermittent slow down.  You have to track GC  so you can eliminate it as a possible source of problems.